# Splitting a string (Segmentation Fault on test)

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to extract a substring from a giving input,
for example if i have : "Hello I am here" in a `char *`
I want to get :

```
char tab[0] = "Hello";
char tab[1] = "I";
/// etc
```

But it gives me a Segfault, any help ?

Here is my function to divide my `char *` :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char    **str_to_wordtab(char *str)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;
  int   k;
  char  **tab;

  i = 0;
  k = 0;
  tab = malloc(my_strlen(str) * sizeof(*tab));
  while (str[k] != '\0')
    {
      j = 0;
      tab[i] = malloc(my_strlen(str) * sizeof(*tab[i]));
      while (str[k] != ' ')
        tab[i][j++] = str[k++];
      tab[i][j] = '\0';
      if (str[k] == ' ')
        k++;
      i++;
    }
return (tab);
}
```

And here is the main to test it :

```
int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  char  **tab;
  int   i;

  i = 0;
  tab = str_to_wordtab("Hello I am here");
  while (tab[i])
    {
      my_putstr(tab[i++]);
      my_putstr("\n");
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: `my_strlen` and `my_putstr` are your custom function? show that function.

Comment: It pass the `str[k] == '\0'` in the loop. and `while (tab[i])` It is not necessarily to have been initialized to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner while loop should look like this:

```
  while (str[k] != ' ')
  {
    tab[i][j++] = str[k++];

    if  (str[k-1] == 0)
    {
      tab[++i] = 0 ;
      return tab ;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a division that you want but a split of string.
Consider `strtok` with space as a delimiter.

About your segfault, here are some leads:

- `while (str[k] != '\0')` might be dangerous if you forgot to recopy the `\0` in your string
- your post-incrementations might be source of errors too